# What is the probability of having more than half of the bits set after randomly flipping a bit $n$ times?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to find the probability that more than half of the bits are set after performing *n* successive random single bit flips, given *k* starting bits all set to 1. To exemplify with three bits, all the possible combinations for the first three bit flips are:

[image: 3 bits 3 flips]

As we can see, after one flip the probability is 1, since it is impossible to reach a configuration with less than two bits set. I would assume that for a large *n* and a large *k* the probability should approach 0.5.

My main interest, if only approximative solutions can be found, is understanding the resilience of a bit sequence like this. Provided that my assumption of an asymptotic behavior approaching 0.5 is correct, how quickly will the probability drop once it starts to drop?

[image]

It is also of interest how this drop is related to the number of bits *k*? For example, what is the probability after *k* successive flips for *k* = 11, 101, 1001, ...?

Comment: "...should approach $0.5$": not if $k$ is even!

Comment: Thank you, for *k* = 4 that’s indeed far from true. In my particular case I will have a large *k* as well. I’ve made a small edit to the original question that clarifies this, even if it will never be theoretically 0.5 for any large and even *k*.

Comment: Are you mainly interested in the asymptotic behavior as $n\to\infty$ and $k>1$ is held fixed, or do you want results for smaller $n$ too?

Comment: My main interest is how quickly the probability drops toward 0.5 for different values of *k* once it starts to drop. For example, for *k* = 101 what happens from the 51st flip and how does this differ from what happens at and after the 501st flip if *k* = 1001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tackle this problem is by using [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). If there are $k$ bits, there are $2^{k}$ possible states for the process to be in. You can then make a stochastic matrix $P$ with $2^{k}$ rows and columns by putting $P_{ij}$ the probability that a single bit flip gets you from state $i$ to state $j$.

For example, if $k=2$ you find $$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}$$
where the first row corresponds to the state $00$, the second one to $10$, the third one to $01$, and the fourth one to $11$. If you start in the $00$ state, this means that you start with the vector $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^{T}$. Computing $P^{n}\mathbf{v}$ now gives you the probability vector after $n$ bit flips.

The probability you're looking for can then be computed by adding all the entries of $P^{n}\mathbf{v}$ that correspond to states with more than half of the bits flipped. In the example, this is only the last state (unless you allow exactly half of the bits to be flipped).

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Markov Chains, but no need to have $2^k$ rows and column. $k+1$ rows and columns is enough.

If you have total $k$ bits, and $j$ bits are set to 1, after the next step, you may have $j-1$ bits set to 1 (proba=$j/k$) or $j+1$ bits set to 1 (proba =$1-j/k$)

So your Markov-Matrix $M$ contains only $2$ sub-diagonals.

You can compute $M^n$  and then multiply this Matrix with vector $(0,0,0...,1)$ to have the law after $n$ switchs.

Asymptotic result is 0.5, of course.

Comment: Of course! This is much more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I am mostly interested in the shape of the curve I realized that an experimental approach should suffice. For that purpose I built a small program that will estimate probabilities for *k* = 11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001. This program can be found here:

https://github.com/Roenbaeck/bitflipper

It will flip *x* random bits 1000 times for 95 different values of *x* >= *k* / 2 and for each *k*. This took about 15 minutes on a desktop PC.

The results are as follows.
[image: 11bits]
[image: 101bits]
[image: 1001bits]
[image: 10001bits]
[image: 100001bits]

Given the results the drop is "quick" in the sense I was looking for in the question. What is interesting though is that the actual drop occurs later relative *k* / 2 the larger *k* is. That feels somewhat counterintuitive.